# Python Argparse - Set default value of a parameter to another parameter

Tags: python, argparse

I've added a parameter -c, now I want to add another parameter called -ca. How can I set the default value of -ca as -c? What I want to do is if -ca is not specified, assign -c to -ca.

```
parser.add_argument("-c", type=str)

parser.add_argument("-ca", type=str, default=XXX)
```

Comment: if `-ca` not specified, then `-c` should be assigned to `-ca`, but if `-c` and `-ca` is not specified then?

Comment: In this case, you can assume -c is mandatory.

Comment: in that case after reading data to arg-parse and handle it after reading from argparse object? what is the problem,? just curious to ask. I will try to write sample and update you too.

Comment: Yes, I could check and then handle it after reading from argparse input. I was just wondering if there's a built-in function to do this without me having to explicitly writing logic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Normally, single dash flags are single characters.  So `-ca` is unwise, though not illegal.  In normal POSIX practice it could be interpreted as `-c a` or `-c -a`.

Also `argparse` allows flagged arguments (`optionals`) to occur in any order.

Parsing starts out by assigning all the defaults.  When the relevant flag is encountered, the new value overwrites the default.  Given that order, it's impossible for one argument to take on the value of another as a default.

In general interactions between arguments are best handled after parsing.  There is a `mutually_exclusive` grouping, but no `mutually_inclusive`.  You can build in some sort of interaction via custom `Action` classes, but implementing that is just as much work as any post-parsing testing.

In sum, the simplest thing is to use the default `default`, `None`, and test

```
if args.ca is None:
    args.ca = args.c
```