# Python (3.6.3) argparse: default value of optional parameter to be another parameter's value

Tags: parameter-passing, python-3.6, argparse, default-value

I have a function that takes as parameters an input folder (required) and output folder (optional), but I want the default value of the (optional) output folder to be the input folder.

I can do this of course using, e.g.

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="blah")
p.add_argument('inpath', type=str, help="Path to input")
p.add_argument('--outpath', required=False, type=str, help="Path to output")

argin = p.parse_args()

if argin.outpath is None:
    argin.outpath = argin.inpath
```

but I want to set the default value in the definition. In another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686317/python-argparse-set-default-value-of-a-parameter-to-another-parameter), the answer is that this is impossible, but i do not trust it, because I have tried

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="blah")
p.add_argument('inpath', type=str, help="Path to input")
p.add_argument('-o', '--outpath', required=False, type=str, 
               default=p.parse_args().inpath, help="Path to output")
```

and this works. The only problem is that if I run my function with the `-h` option, I don't see the `--outpath` option there; I get

```
usage: argparse_test.py [-h] inpath

positional arguments:
  inpath      Path to input files.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

The same happens, if I make function, say

```
def assign():
    return p.parse_args().inpath
```

and set the `default` parameter in the `add_argument()` method to `assign`:

```
p.add_argument('-o', '--outpath', required=False, type=str, default=assign(),
               help="Path to output")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In my humble opinion, your first attempt is the best approach. Making things explicit is better than making things compact but complicated. And logically, your second attempt seems to cause a chicken-or-the-egg problem. Your `p.parse_args()` is dependent on the result of your `p.add_argument()`, whereas your `p.add_argument()` is dependent on your `p.parse_args()` (using it as an argument for `default`).

Comment: Just like @aafulei said. The point of *argparse* module is to help you parse arguments, not to write your program logic in it.

Comment: The `p.parse_args().inpath` expression sees and catches the `-h`, returning `p` before `output` was defined. The post parsing processing is simplest and most reliable - as argued in my linked answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I thought that would be the case, but since I'd rather have this in the definition (if it were possible), I thought I'd take my chances with a question here.